# How can I remove space at the top of my HTML page?

Tags: javascript, html, css, margins

I wanna give some space in the top though my css have margin:0 auto;

And this is the css :

```
* {
   margin:0 auto;
   padding:0;
   border:0;
   outline:0;
   vertical-align: baseline;
   background:#eee;
   overflow-x: hidden;
   }

   header {
   width:100vw;
   height:300px;
   background:red;
   }
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qsqEY.png)

Codepen: http://codepen.io/ciocigabi79/pen/NbXWRz

Comment: Post your html too.

Comment: could you just show us in jsfiddle or codepen?

Comment: Can you put up a fiddle ?

Comment: must be something else, your code works fine like so: https://jsfiddle.net/2jh67gx6/

Comment: It will be easier if you post your html.

Comment: There are empty characters in your html. Check code pen you will see small white dots in the first 2-3 lines. Remove them and all will be good.

Comment: @hunzaboy seems like the indentation was the problem ...is this possible ?

Comment: @CiociGabi, its not the indentation, i assume you copied the html structure from a website, that ususally causes it.

Comment: @hunzaboy ty very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had some unusual characters in your html, which were causing the issue. Just remove the first character from your codepen (the dots) and it'll work fine.

Indendation doesn't cause this problem, but if there are these invisible characters, they can cause various problems. I remember, I had a similar problem when my php API response looked good, but couldn't be parsed due to a similar character at the beginning of the response.

Here's your updated pen

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PbEojQ

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="icon" href="img/favicon.png">
    <script src="javascript.js"></script>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body><header></header>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you sure can indent but using spaces and tabs only. some special characters are not visible but can cause problems